# How to conditionally apply nested SCSS classes in ReactJS based on a boolean prop?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, jsx

I have a sidebar navigational element that I'm attempting to apply SCSS styles to based on the position of the element, in React. This is what I currently have for the combination of CSS classes imported from a module:

```
styles.main,
styles[position],
isOpen ? styles.opened : styles.closed,
```

The snippet from the SCSS file:

```
.right {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;

  .opened {
    visibility: visible;
  }

  .closed {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to have the SCSS styles be applied correctly. The elements are inheriting the `.main` class and the root selector for `.right` (containing the `top` and `right` attributes), but not the ones for `.right.opened` and `.right.closed`.

Any help or pointers as to where I'm going wrong would be MUCH appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to inherit the styles, but compose them. Instead of having:

```
.right {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;

  .opened {
    visibility: visible;
  }

  .closed {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

you have to do:

```
.right {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;

  &__opened {
    visibility: visible;
  }

  &__closed {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

Then, you will apply classes like `isOpen ? styles.right__opened : styles.right__closed`.

You can check [my demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/18mxl47497).

Comment: That's definitely good to know, but my issue is still mainly that I need the `[position]` element to be dynamic - something like: `isOpen ? styles.[position]__opened : styles.[position]__closed`, which won't work

Comment: Aha - nevermind, I used the same concept to apply it to how I currently have it set in the React `.jsx` file (like so: `&.opened` and `&.closed`), and that worked as expected. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) utility, it is the currently recommended approach to handle conditional CSS class names in ReactJs.

Comment: Is there anything else that I could do that wouldn't involve adding additional packages?